# AWS S3 iOS - Know when listing objects is finished

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3

I'm listing all the objects in an S3 bucket using the following function

```
    let s3 = AWSS3.default()
    let listObjectsRequest = AWSS3ListObjectsV2Request()

    s3.listObjectsV2(listObjectsRequest!) { (result, error) in
      ...
    }
```

It's an asynchronous function. How can I know when the listing is done using Swift 3? I have an activity indicator that is running and stops when the listing is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it had a completion handler.

I just added the code to stop the animation at the bottom of the listObjectsV2.

Just remember to update the UI inside a main queue

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
       // Bounce back to the main thread to update the UI
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           // Stop animation
       }
}
```